# Combining factor level in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like combine level "A","B" into "A+B". I successfully did this by the following:

```
x <- factor(c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","C"))
x
#[1] A B A C D E A E C
#Levels: A B C D E
l <- c("A+B","A+B","C","D+E","D+E")
factor(l[as.numeric(x)])
#[1] A+B A+B A+B C   D+E D+E A+B D+E C  
#Levels: A+B C D+E
```

Is there any more trivial way to do this? (i.e. more explainable function name such as **combine.factor(f, old.levels, new.levels)** would help to understand the code easier.)

Also, I try to find a well named function which probably work with data frame in *dplyr* package but no luck. The closest implementation is

```
df %>% mutate(x = factor(l[as.numeric(x)]))
```

Comment: You don't need `as.numeric`, i.e. `factor(l[x])` also works. And you can easily write your own `combine.factor` function

Comment: Also `levels(x)<-l` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is `recode` from `car`

```
library(car)
recode(x, "c('A', 'B')='A+B';c('D', 'E') = 'D+E'")
#[1] A+B A+B A+B C   D+E D+E A+B D+E C  
#Levels: A+B C D+E
```

It should also work with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(x= recode(x, "c('A', 'B')='A+B';c('D', 'E') = 'D+E'"))
#    x
#1 A+B
#2 A+B
#3 A+B
#4   C
#5 D+E
#6 D+E
#7 A+B
#8 D+E
#9   C
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x)
```

Answer (score 15):

This is now easy to do with [`fct_collapse()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forcats/versions/0.4.0/topics/fct_collapse) from the [`forcats`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forcats/versions/0.4.0) package.

```
x <- factor(c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","C"))

library(forcats)
fct_collapse(x, AB = c("A","B"), DE = c("D","E"))

#[1] AB AB AB C  DE DE AB DE C 
#Levels: AB C DE
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `ifelse()` to create a new factor?

```
x = factor(c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","C"))
# chained comparisons, a single '|' works on the whole vector
y = as.factor(
    ifelse(x=='A'|x=='B',
        'A+B',
        ifelse(x=='D'|x=='E','D+E','C')
    )
)
> y
[1] A+B A+B A+B C   D+E D+E A+B D+E C  
Levels: A+B C D+E

# using %in% to search
z = as.factor(
    ifelse(x %in% c('A','B'),
        'A+B',
        ifelse(x %in% c('D','E'),'D+E','C'))
)
> z
[1] A+B A+B A+B C   D+E D+E A+B D+E C  
Levels: A+B C D+E
```

If you don't want to hard-code in the factor level `C` above, or if you have more than one factor level that does not need to be combined, you can use the following.

```
# Added new factor levels
x = factor(c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","C","New","Stuff","Here"))
w = as.factor(
    ifelse(x %in% c('A','B'),
        'A+B',
        ifelse(x %in% c('D','E'),
            'D+E',
            as.character(x) # without the cast it's numeric
        )
    )
)
> w
[1] A+B   A+B   A+B   C     D+E   D+E   A+B   D+E   C     New   Stuff Here
Levels: A+B C D+E Here New Stuff
```