# Grouping elements in data frame

Tags: r

Say I have a variable in a data frame which can take values "a", "b", "c", "d" and "e". It may look something like this:

```
V1
c
d
e
e
d
e
a
c
b
b
```

However, I know/suspect that "a" and "b" describes pretty much the samt thing, as well as "c" and "d". Therefore, I want to create a new variable where these have the same value, i.e.

```
V1 V2
c  c
d  c
e  e
e  e
d  c
e  e
a  a
c  c
b  a
b  a
```

I thought this would be easy, but I can't find a way to do it!

Comment: In your question, you should post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use

```
library(car)
df1$V2 <- recode(df1$V1, "'d'='c';'b'='a'")
df1$V2
#[1] "c" "c" "e" "e" "c" "e" "a" "c" "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you couldn't just use:

```
df$V2 <- df$V1
df$V2[df$V2=="d"] <- "c"
df$V2[df$V2=="b"] <- "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

I post a similar question a day before.

My solution was:

```
l <- c("a","a","c","c","e")
factor(l[V1])
```

Using dplyr packages:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(V2 = factor(l[V1]))
```

Please refer to this thread for more answer:

[Combining factor level in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568758/combining-factor-level-in-r/36568891)